# whats wrong with my code? i just started with C# and i dont know whats going on

Tags: c#, selenium, error-handling

I just started coding with C# and i keep getting this error 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' and i dont know what i did wrong anyone able to help? I keep getting this message

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

I tried looking around but didnt find anything.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\webdrivers");
        //textbox input
       // string quest = question1.Text;

        //random choise
     
        var random = new Random();
        var Names = question1.Text.Split();
        int index = random.Next();

//the error is here\\
        string randomName = Names[index];
        
        driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("whsOnd")).SendKeys(randomName);
        
        
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\webdrivers");
        ChromeDriver drv; Thread th;
        string url = "google.com";

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

    }
}
```

Comment: Change `int index = random.Next();` to `int index = random.Next(Names.Length);`

Comment: `random.Next()` will give you a number between 0 and 2147483647, you don't have that many items in the `Names` array.

Comment: Debugger is your friend. Create a breakpoint at `string randomName = Names[index];` and see how many items stored at `var Names` and what is your `index` value. If `index` is greater than amount of `Names` or less than 0 - that's a reason for exception you get.

Comment: i have 1 more question i have a list which is connected to a textbox that part works fine but the issue is when i send names i want it to pick the 1st one the the 2nd one and so on... will i need to write the amount of code i need to send each of the names or is there a way around it? sorry if this questions are stupid but really confused. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

"Index was outside the bounds of the array" suggests that the random index generated is larger than the size of your `Names` array

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.  In fact, some of the comments are better answers (and, no, I'm not the downvoter).

Comment: But it does answer the question of "What's going wrong with my code?". It doesn't provide a solution but it does help the OP to find the solution.